# A box loop-integral

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, integration, dimensional-regularization

I am trying to evaluate the integrate
$$
\int\frac{d^Dk}{(2 \pi)^D} \frac{1}{(k^2)^2(k^2-m^2)}
$$ using dimensional regularisation ($D=4-2\epsilon$). From various references it appears that it should be proportional to $\frac{1}{\epsilon} + \frac{3}{4}+\frac{1}{2}\ln\frac{\mu^2}{m^2}$. However, when I evaluate it, I get (using Feynman parametrisation)

$$\mu^{4-D}\int_0^1du \left( u (1-u)^{-1-\epsilon)} \right) \left(m^2 \right)^{-1-\epsilon} \Gamma(\frac{6-D}{2})$$
Using the definition of the beta function and expanding the gamma functions in $\epsilon$ I get a result proportional to
$$
\frac{1}{\epsilon} + \ln \frac{\mu^2}{m^2} - \gamma_E
$$
where the last constant is Euler's constant.